# what is Time Complexity of generating number from uniform(int x,int y) function of random library in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, time-complexity

```
random.uniform(x,y)
```

Can someone please explain me how does this function generates a random number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that `random.uniform` is a real-valued/continuous distribution, so it interprets parameters as floats rather than ints.  if you really want an integer version, then you probably want `randint` or `randrange`.

- the complexity of `uniform` is independent of the parameters so it's just `O(1)`. it just generates 64 uniformly distributed bits and transforms them into a float, see [`Random_random` in _randommodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Modules/_randommodule.c#L171)
- `randrange` does depend on the parameters, namely it needs enough bits to generate a distinct value for every possible value. hence it's `O(log n)`, where `n` is the number of choices in the range.  see [`Random.randrange` in random.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L291)

note that I'm describing recent CPython here, other implementations might do different things, e.g. the [docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) that that in older versions of CPython `randrange` was implicitly O(1) and hence wouldn't have the possibility of generating every value in large ranges, as well as being slightly biased

Comment: Thanks for helping out [Sam Mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358308/sam-mason)